# Make a Div appear half off-screen

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make a `div` appear half off-screen using just CSS without knowing the width of the `div`?

Comment: what about setting the left to -50px or likewise

Comment: How can he do that if he doesn't know the width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood the question, I think it *is* possible with CSS, as I hope should be clear from [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magicalex/qe6Bq/).

Example HTML

```
<div class="container one">
   <div class="half">Hello there.</div>
</div>
   <div class="container two">
<div class="half">Hello there, you old dog.</div>
   </div>
<div class="container three">
   <div class="half">Hello there you old dog. Been up to your old tricks?</div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
}
.half {
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
}
.two {
    top: 30px;
}
.three {
    top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no.

The `div` will have it's top positioned at 50% the screen... you could assume values that would "sort of" make it look like it would be in the middle if you knew more or less the height of the div before-hand. But in short, no.

**Only with tables or Javascript.**

Comment: How would you use tables? Could you use `display: table`?

Comment: No, you would create a table with 3 rows (remember the 3 row, 3 collums?)... old style really. Would not recommend.

Comment: I guess you are older than I am Frankie =). I don't know that trick.

Comment: Humm... old-style meaning old-style web... any site from 2000 would probably have a table to sort out the elements position. Then you would have sub-tables on cells... it was a <td> nightmare! :)

Answer (score 0):

i made something from jQuery. Hope its what you are after - http://jsfiddle.net/6Guc8/1/.  it gets half the width of the element and then chucks half of it out the screen.

here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var half_width = $("div").width() / 2;
    $("div").css("left", -half_width);
});
```

here is the css

```
div{
    background: #555;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;  
    position: absolute;
}
```

here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">          </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible in CSS only. You need 1 wrapper div, however:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div#wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
        }
        div#wrapper div {
            position: relative;
            padding: 30px;
            background: yellow;
            left: -50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div>this div is halfway hidden, no matter what size it is.</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```